# Problem while reading public key from .pem certificate into a variable in Python

Tags: python-3.x, cryptography, certificate

I wanted to extract Public key from `.pem` certificate using cryptography library in Python. But I am facing problem.
Here is the code :

```
from cryptography import x509
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.x509.oid import NameOID
pem_cert=open("/home/lab14/aes/fd.pem","rb").read()
cert = x509.load_pem_x509_certificate(pem_cert, default_backend())
pub_key = cert.public_key()
print(pub_key)
```

This is the output I am getting :

```
<cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.rsa._RSAPublicKey object at 0x7f266caa36d8>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Uh, I changed your question title to read ".pem" instead of ".per". Now, a certificate in .per format would pose great difficulty (read up on ASN.1 / PER format to understand why: it's a bit oriented encoding format).

Answer (score 2):

That is not an error. It is the representation of the RSAPublicKey object. So your code works, now you need to do something with the object. Check the documentation on the available properties and methods that the object provides.

Comment: For example, `pub_key.public_numbers().n` is more interesting.